# Save .pptm as .pptx, close and delete .pptm

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

I have a macro that I am using to make 250 ppts. The macro I have made replaces the filepath to images in the file with images within the same folder and updates a couple text boxes in the ppt with the name of the containing folder. What I would like to be able to do is run the code and save the file as a pptx in the same folder as the active presentation and close and delete the pptm file. As of right now, it saves the file in the folder one level above for some reason. Any ideas?

***BONUS POINTS:***
I am on Mac, so whenever I replace the links for the images, I have to grant access to the new link. I have searched around for answers for this, but looks like there might not be a way around this. But thought I'd ask, just in case there may be a new way around it.

```
Sub EditPowerPointLinks()

Dim oldFilePath As String
Dim newFilePath As String
Dim pptPresentation As Presentation
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape
Dim idnName As String
Dim saveName As String
Dim folderName As String

folderName = ActivePresentation.Path

longName = Right(folderName, Len(folderName) - 39)
idnName = Left(longName, Len(longName) - 5)

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = idnName
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = idnName & " | 2023"

'The old file path as a string (the text to be replaced)
oldFilePath = "File Path"

'The new file path as a string (the text to replace with)
newFilePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "/Images/"

'Set the variable to the PowerPoint Presentation
Set pptPresentation = ActivePresentation

'Loop through each slide in the presentation
For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides

    'Loop through each shape in each slide
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
   
        'Find out if the shape is a linked object or a linked picture
        If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or pptShape.Type _
        = msoLinkedOLEObject Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedChart Then

            'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath
            pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(LCase _
            (pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), LCase(oldFilePath), newFilePath)
            
        End If
    Next
Next

'Update the links
pptPresentation.UpdateLinks

With ActivePresentation
    .SaveAs _
        FileName:=folderName & "_File Name.pptx", _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You set `folderName` to `ActivePresentation.Path` - probably you are simply missing a "/" between `folderName` and the filename for the presentation.

Comment: as per above comment, i would change this `FileName:=folderName & "_Clinical Guidelines and Pathways Implementation.pptx",` to this `FileName:=folderName & "\" &"_Clinical Guidelines and Pathways Implementation.pptx",`

Comment: Here is Ron de Bruin's page about avoiding the Grant Access problem. This page is about Excel, but the information applies to PowerPoint and Word as well: https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/sandbox/

Comment: Thank you, both of these suggestions work! I ended up going with: FileName:=folderName & "/" & longName & "_Clinical Guidelines and Pathways Implementation.pptx", _

Comment: Any ideas on the closing and deleting the pptm file?

Comment: Why not store the VBA in a separate file rather than trying to remove it from the file you've just created?

Comment: I guess I don't necessarily need to have a pptm file in the folder, but I do need there to be a file in the folder to open in order for ActivePresentation to work. So, it can be a pptx file, as long as I have a pptm file with the proper code in it. Is there a way to just update the name file of the active presentation, without doing a saveas? Because even with it being a pptx, I still have to delete the file I open after running the script. Not a huge deal, but definitely an unnecessary step.

Comment: It would be awesome if there was some kind of batch code that I could run to open each pptx in a list of folders, run the macro, close the file, delete the template file, and move on to the next folder. I know there's gotta be a way to do it. But it's just not something my brain can comprehend haha.

Comment: I seemed to have figured out how to close and delete the file using:

```
Kill (folderName & "/" & "File Template.pptx")

With Application.Presentations(folderName & "/" & longName & "_File.pptx")
    .Saved = True
    .Close
End With
```

Thank you for the help!